# NAO robot does not detect green light

Tags: python, computer-vision, nao-robot

I used `AlColorBlobDetection` to detect the green light (I have a toy traffic light which switches colors), however, it looks like my robot tracks the light or white color, but definitely not the green color. I attached the code. I use choreographe.

```
class MyClass(GeneratedClass):

def __init__(self):

GeneratedClass.__init__(self)



def onLoad(self):

# put initialization code here

pass



def onUnload(self):

# put clean-up code here

pass



def onInput_onStart(self):

motion = ALProxy("ALMotion")

posture = ALProxy("ALRobotPosture")

tracker = ALProxy("ALTracker")



# First, wake up.

motion.wakeUp()



fractionMaxSpeed = 0.8

# Go to posture stand

posture.goToPosture("StandInit", fractionMaxSpeed)



motionProxy = ALProxy("ALColorBlobDetection")

motionProxy.setColor(0,250,0, 200)

eventName = "ALTracker/ColorBlobDetected"

# set mode

mode = "Head"

tracker.setMode(mode)



# Then, start tracker.

tracker.trackEvent(eventName)



print "ALTracker successfully started, now show green color to robot!"

print "Use Ctrl+c to stop this script."



try:

while True:

time.sleep(1)

except KeyboardInterrupt:

print

print "Interrupted by user"

print "Stopping..."



# Stop tracker, go to posture Sit.

tracker.stopTracker()

tracker.unregisterAllTargets()

posture.goToPosture("Sit", fractionMaxSpeed)

motion.rest()



print "ALTracker stopped."



def onInput_onStop(self):

self.onUnload() # it is recommended to reuse the clean-up as the box is stopped

self.onStopped() # activate the output of the box
```

Comment: Could you share a picture taken from NAO's camera of what your green light looks like?